# How to custom format table data with BootstrapVue?

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using *BootstrapVue's Table component* and *Luxon* and trying to format an ISO date using the 'formatter callback' to customize the date output to something more human readable.

Unfortunately, I get an error `Invalid DateTime`

Sample data `../assets/users.json"`:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Salmon",
      "last_name": "Searight",
      "email": "ssearight0@usda.gov",
      "gender": "Male",
      "ip_address": "186.63.72.254",
      "date_assigned": "2019-07-15T12:58:06.382Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Marika",
      "last_name": "Cloonan",
      "email": "mcloonan1@phpbb.com",
      "gender": "Female",
      "ip_address": "247.143.78.216",
      "date_assigned": "2019-07-15T12:58:06.382Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Dyan",
      "last_name": "Dainter",
      "email": "ddainter2@yolasite.com",
      "gender": "Female",
      "ip_address": "234.16.229.89",
      "date_assigned": "2019-07-15T12:58:06.382Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my attempt (with [sample sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/bootstrap-vue-table-with-date-formatting-o93gk)):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table :items="users" :fields="fields">
      <!-- A custom formatted column -->
      <template slot="name" slot-scope="data">{{ data.value.userId }}</template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import users from "../assets/users.json";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
      fields: [
        { key: "id" },
        { key: "first_name" },
        { key: "date_assigned", formatter: "formatDateAssigned" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    formatDateAssigned(value) {
      const formattedDate = DateTime.fromISO(
        value.date_assigned
      ).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT);
      return formattedDate;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Does anyone spot anything that is causing the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from the value used inside the formatter, the value passed to the formatter function is already the one you want, you don't need to use the field key inside.

Just replace `value.date_assigned` to `value` inside your `formatDateAssigned` function.